# C# How to obtain 2 separate class value nodes and write them to a datatable/dgv

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I seem to have everything working on the name loop, but when loading the which is assigning the players name to the name column in the datagridview, but the position column appears to be looping continuously and not associating the correct value for each player.

```
public void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt6 = new DataTable();
    dt6.Columns.Add("Name");
    dt6.Columns.Add("Position");
    DataRow row;

    var doc = new HtmlWeb().Load("https://www.numberfire.com/nba/daily-fantasy/daily-basketball-projections");
    foreach (HtmlNode node1 in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//span[@class='player-info']//a[2]"))
    {
        foreach (HtmlNode node2 in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//span[@class='player-info--position']"))
        {
            row = dt6.NewRow();
            row["Name"] = node1.InnerHtml.Trim();
            row["Position"] = node2.InnerHtml.Trim();
            dt6.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
    dataGridView4.DataSource = dt6;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
    public void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataTable dt6 = new DataTable();
        dt6.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt6.Columns.Add("Position");
        DataRow row;



        var doc = new HtmlWeb().Load("https://www.numberfire.com/nba/daily-fantasy/daily-basketball-projections");


        foreach (HtmlNode node1 in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='player-info']"))
        {
            row = dt6.NewRow();

            foreach (HtmlNode node in node1.SelectNodes(".//a"))
            {

                row["Name"] = node.InnerHtml.Trim();

            }
                foreach (HtmlNode node2 in node1.SelectNodes(".//span[@class='player-info--position']"))
                {

                    row["Position"] = node2.InnerText.Trim();

                }
            dt6.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        dataGridView4.DataSource = dt6;
        }
```